# Blackberry finer control over phone call - access to audio stream

Tags: audio, stream, blackberry, phone-call

I want to make a blackberry application which could access the audio stream during a phone call and modify it. Is this possible using some of the rim apis? The idea is to be able to change your voice during a phone call and the person on the other end to hear your voice differently. I need finer control over the phone call.

Answer (score 1):

There are no RIM APIs that allow you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible in Blackberry....